# how do I use browser detection code to run certain HTML depending on detection result?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-detection

I found this code snippet when I followed a link here on Stackoverflow.  It is exactly what I need, but I'm not sure how to implement it. I'd like to use it to run specific code depending on browser.  For example, if Firefox, then simply use linked Javascript, if IE/Chrome, then I'd like to use alternate code (HTML and JS).

How can this be done?

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera') >= 0;
// Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
// At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !!window.chrome;                          // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;                            // At least IE6

document.write('isFirefox: ' + isFirefox + '<br>');
document.write('isChrome: ' + isChrome + '<br>');
document.write('isSafari: ' + isSafari + '<br>');
document.write('isOpera: ' + isOpera + '<br>');
document.write('isIE: ' + isIE + '<br>');
```

Comment: Why do you want to detect the browser? What is your plan if the user isn't using any of the five browsers mentioned in that code? Best practice is just to detect whether a particular feature is available. (But if you feel you _must_ do something based on the browser you just need to use the `isFirefox` and other variables in an `if` test: `if (isFirefox) { /* do something */ }`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I tested this particular code and it works perfectly in Chrome, IE, and Firefox, so I'd like to give it a shot. I have certain code that only works in certain browsers and I tested that as well.  My next question is tho, how do I execute HTML/JS after the "if" statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isFirefox) {

    // do FireFox stuff here

} else if (isChrome) {

    // do Chrome stuff here

} else if (isSafari) {

    // do Safari stuff here

} else if (isOpera) {

    // do Opera stuff here

} else if (isIE) {

    // do IE stuff here

} else {

    // other browser

}
```

Comment: Does anyone know to do this using Smarty templates? The PHP backbone file is really simple, and everything goes on in the template.  But I don't know how to do it...help please?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Modernizr, it's exactly what you need, and is the proper way to do browser sniffing.

http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link!  If my first approach doesn't work, I'll check it out!